# Language detection always returns 1 result

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm having troubles with getting Language Detection to work. According to the documentation on [Microsoft's website](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7) I should be able to get multiple languages when the service is not sure about which language the input string was. However, I am always receiving only one language. In my example below I used "Hallo" which is "Hello" in both German and Dutch. Also with other words like "Bier" which is "Beer" in German and Dutch, the service gives only one result, despite the numberOfLanguages Query parameter value of 5.

- Am I missing something?
- Is the service malfunctioning?
- Can someone provide an example which delivers multiple languages as a result?

Thank you for all your help.

Request:

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages?numberOfLanguagesToDetect=5 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "Test",
      "text": "Hallo"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this response:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-ms-transaction-count: 0
x-aml-ta-request-id: 4bb2e01e-59a1-4f66-bb31-8ca2c32d262b
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
apim-request-id: 65a8d5f5-1394-43cf-89e1-83d7188cb81a
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 15:18:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "Test",
      "detectedLanguages": [
        {
          "name": "German",
          "iso6391Name": "de",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Comment: I tried a few simple tests but couldn't get multiple languages to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation has been updated to explain this.

> **numberOfLanguagesToDetect**: Format - int32. (Optional. Deprecated) Number of languages to detect. Set to 1 by default. **Irrespective of
>   the value, the language with the highest score is returned.**